# Difficulty counting the number of divs in external html file ( get and find) - jquery

Tags: jquery, get

So this is my jquery function - it is supposed to find and return to console the number of divs in an external file as a callback from a get request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function(){



    $.get('source.html', function(data){
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    var count = ($(data).find('div').size());
    console.log(count);
    });


    console.log ($("body").find('div').size());

    });

});
```

I get an alert containing the correct data from source.html (which contains 2 divs) but the count var always comes up as 0? Any ideas please you wonderful people?

HTML here for source.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
<head>
    <title>Source</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="div1">
    You got loaded xxxx.
</div>
<div id="div2">
    You got loaded again xxxx.
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: size function has been deprecated so use the .length to find the number of div. http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: `.size()` is depracated as of 1.8, use `.length` instead http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'length' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: Of course you are right there. Removed the parenthesis and got rid of the error from length but I am still getting a big fat zero in my console for div count.

Comment: run this in the chrome console. `$.get('google.com', function(data){ console.log($(data).find('div').length) })` you should get 91

Comment: TypeError: Object function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } has no method 'get'

Comment: Try the method i put in the answer.

Comment: Must have mistyped, now getting 104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything you've tried failed...

Try adding it to a jQuery element

```
$.get('source.html', function(data){ 
  var count = $('<div></div>').html(data).find('div').length; 
  console.log(count);
});
```

Check to see if you get 2 or 3.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that gives me 2. Thanks very much. Can we assume that there is a type problem then at the point I am assigning the result of ($(data).find('div').size()); to count?